# Ubuntu installation error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I get an error while trying to install ubuntu in my lenovo thinkpad laptop.

I have made a bootable pen drive of ubuntu iso image [UEFI] using rufus tool.Please help me, to get out from this error. I want to install ubuntu only in single boot.

Here is the image of error given below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Input/output error** is usually caused by damaged HW. These errors

Connect pen drive to another computer and check filesystem by `fsck` or `gnome-disks` or some similar utility.

If you found other errors in `dmesg` it's better to throw the pen drive into the thrash and buy a new one...